# Imagestring foreach loop?

Tags: php, image, foreach

I am trying to add a new line within a foreach loop using imagestring, but it keeps showing the information on the same line
Here is the image and you can see the mistake I dont need to point it out
[Image Link](http://seahaventrucking.com/driverstats2.php)

```
<?php

if (count($rows) == 0) {
    imagestring($image, $fontsize, $leftside, 90, "NO JOBS DETECTED", $font_white);
}

foreach($rows as $key=>$row) {
    $query = "
    SELECT username FROM users";
    $query_params = array(':id' => $row['driver']);
    $query .= "WHERE id = :id";

    try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    $driver = $stmt->fetch();
    $driver = $driver['username'];

    imagestring($image, $fontsize, $leftside, 100, "Top 5 Drivers", $font_red);
    imagestring($image, $fontsize, $leftside, $linedown, ($key+1).'..' . $driver, $font_red);
}
```

Comment: Is this about javascript? if so, add the tag, add some code (not a link, actual code), and explain the problem

Comment: no javascript all php, link to the code is there cuz I DONT KNOW HOW TO PROPERLY INSERT THE CODE, the link to my image is also there so you can see where the error is

Comment: Hi user3400268 -- Welcome to SO. You can create a code block by adding four spaces to the beginning of each line or using the {} symbol in the text editor window.

Comment: And you can view further formatting tips here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify/81970#81970

Comment: thanks for cleaning up the code but that doesnt help me with the issue